# Are finite length objects preserved under exact functors between abelian categories?

Tags: abelian-categories, functors

Let $C,D$ be abelian categories and let $F:C\rightarrow D$ be an exact functor. I wonder if is it true that if $A$ is a finite length object in $C$ then $F(A)$ is finite length in $D$.

Since we assume that $F$ is exact, the question reduces to prove or disprove that if $A$ is a simple object then $F(A)$ is finite length object.

In case it is not true, I would love to see a counterexample for that.

Thanks.

Comment: Let V be an infinite dimensional vector space over some field K. The functor that maps a vector space U to V\otimes U is exact.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez Very clear example, thanks. If we impose that such an exact functor induces an equivalence of abelian categories, will it be true then that it takes simple objects to finite length objects? Or we can also find some counterexample for that case?

Comment: If the functor is an equivalence then sure, it will preserve simple objects, finite length objects and, in fact, pretty much anything else.